# Android - Taking a screenshot of what's behind a CardView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building an application that allows a user to take a screenshot of a portion of the device's screen and display it on a `CardView` (id: `parent`). I followed [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-draw-over-other-apps-in-android/) tutorial to allow your app to draw over other apps and stay visible even when the application is quit. The way this works is that the `MainActivity` starts a `ForegroundService` which in turn instantiates a new `Window` where the popup with a button and a CardView above appears. Furthermore, a `screenShot` method is called in the `Window` class whenever the popup button is clicked and displays whatever is on the `CardView` above (for now, nothing as it is white). I was wondering if there is a way to get the portion of the screen directly behind the `CardView` to display on the `CardView` itself.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        checkOverlayPermission();
        startService();
    }

    // method for starting the service
    public void startService(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            // check if the user has already granted
            // the Draw over other apps permission
            if(Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                // start the service based on the android version
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    startForegroundService(new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class));
                } else {
                    startService(new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class));
                }
            }
        }else {
            startService(new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class));
        }
    }

    // method to ask user to grant the Overlay permission
    public void checkOverlayPermission(){

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                // send user to the device settings
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    // check for permission again when user grants it from
    // the device settings, and start the service
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startService();
    }
}
```

**ForegroundService.java**

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service {
    public ForegroundService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // create the custom or default notification
        // based on the android version
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            startMyOwnForeground();
        else
            startForeground(1, new Notification());

        // create an instance of Window class
        // and display the content on screen
        Window window=new Window(this);
        window.open();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    // for android version >=O we need to create
    // custom notification stating
    // foreground service is running
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void startMyOwnForeground()
    {
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "example.permanence";
        String channelName = "Background Service";
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert manager != null;
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle("Service running")
                .setContentText("Displaying over other apps")

                // this is important, otherwise the notification will show the way
                // you want i.e. it will show some default notification
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)

                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .build();
        startForeground(2, notification);
    }
}
```

**Window.java**

```
public class Window {

    // declaring required variables
    private Context context;
    private View mView;
    private WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams;
    private WindowManager mWindowManager;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    ImageView screenShot;

    public Window(Context context){
        this.context=context;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            // set the layout parameters of the window
            mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    // Shrink the window to wrap the content rather
                    // than filling the screen
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    // Display it on top of other application windows
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                    // Don't let it grab the input focus
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    // Make the underlying application window visible
                    // through any transparent parts
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        }
        // getting a LayoutInflater
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // inflating the view with the custom layout we created
        mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null);
        final CardView parent=mView.findViewById(R.id.parent);
        screenShot=mView.findViewById(R.id.screenShot);
        // set onClickListener on the remove button, which removes
        // the view from the window
        mView.findViewById(R.id.window_close).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                screenShot(parent);
                //close();
            }
        });
        // Define the position of the
        // window within the screen
        mParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        mWindowManager = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    }

    public void screenShot(View view) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        screenShot.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    public void open() {

        try {
            // check if the view is already
            // inflated or present in the window
            if(mView.getWindowToken()==null) {
                if(mView.getParent()==null) {
                    mWindowManager.addView(mView, mParams);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error1",e.toString());
        }

    }

    public void close() {

        try {
            // remove the view from the window
            ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(mView);
            // invalidate the view
            mView.invalidate();
            // remove all views
            ((ViewGroup)mView.getParent()).removeAllViews();

            // the above steps are necessary when you are adding and removing
            // the view simultaneously, it might give some exceptions
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error2",e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**popup_window.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:background="@null">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/screenShot"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleText"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Displaying over other apps!"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:padding="10dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/window_close"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Remove" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use the media projection APIs to take a screenshot without the `CardView` in place. You have no other means of capturing the screen content of another app, and you would need to be not showing the `CardView` at the time (as otherwise that will be in the screenshot).

Comment: How can I achieve this from the `Window` class as I would need the `startActivityForResult` method to perform a screenshot? If I were to do this from the `MainActivity` class, is there a way to reference the popup's elements there?

Comment: "How can I achieve this from the Window class as I would need the startActivityForResult method to perform a screenshot?" -- you would need to get permission from the activity and pass the details to your service when you start that service. See the media projection chapter in [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Android/) for examples.